# Can't figure out what the problem is in TIC TAC TOE, detailed description of problems in the body below [Python 3]

Tags: python, python-3.x

Heys guys, thanks for taking the time to view my code. This is basically the fist fully interactive "Project" I've written since I started my Python Lessons in mid September. The game runs and you'll get to play with a display. But the issues that I'm struggling to figure out are:

1- Once a Player Actually wins, it doesn't display the win message (A.K.A the function doesn't execute properly)

2- Once the board is full, the full_board_check() function does not execute properly either so no TIE message is displayed

3- Sometimes the player Turn gets stuck on either player 1 or player 2 and never changes turns again.

Thank you in advance to everyone that takes their time to help me diagnose and debug my first project.

```
#TIC TAC TOE Milestone Project Jack Version

#FUNCTION TO ASSIGN A PLAYER MARKER GLOBALLY 

import random


def player_assignment():
global player1
global player2

player1=''

while player1 not in ['X','O']:

    player1=input('Hello Player 1, are you gonna be X or O?')

if player1 == 'X':


    player2 = 'O'

else:

    player2 = 'X'


#FUNCTION TO DISPLAY THE GAME BOARD
def display_board(board):
    print('    '+board[7]+'    '+'|'+'    '+board[8]+'    '+'|'+'    '+board[9]+'    ')
    print('-----------------------')
    print('    '+board[4]+'    '+'|'+'    '+board[5]+'    '+'|'+'    '+board[6]+'    ')
    print('-----------------------')
    print('    '+board[1]+'    '+'|'+'    '+board[2]+'    '+'|'+'    '+board[3]+'    ')


#FUNCTION TO RETURN PLAYER POSITION CHOICE 
def player_choice():

    position = 0

    while position not in range(1,10):

        position = int(input('Choose a Position 1-9'))

    return int(position)


#THIS IS THE FUNCTION THAT WILL PLACE PLAYER'S CHOICE AT POSITION
def place_marker(board,player,position):
    board[position]=player


#FUNCTION TO CHECK WHOSE TURN IT IS 
def turn():
    number = random.randint(0,1)

    if number == 0:
        return 'Player 1'

    else:
        return 'Player 2'


#THIS WILL CHECK IF THERES A WIN ACROsS ROWS AND COLUMNS AS A BOOLEAN
def win_check(board,marker):

    return ((board[1] == board[2] == board[3] == marker) or
(board[4] == board[5] == board[6] == marker) or 
(board[7] == board[8] == board[9] == marker) or
(board[7] == board[4] == board[1] == marker) or
(board[8] == board[5] == board[2] == marker) or
(board[9] == board[6] == board[3] == marker) or
(board[1] == board[5] == board[9] == marker) or 
(board[3] == board[5] == board[7] == marker) )

#THIS WILL CHECK IF THE BOARD IS FULL TO DETERMINE IF ITS A TIE OR NOT
def full_board_check(board):
    return '' not in board






    #LETS START THE GAME


    #FIRST THINGS FIRST
print('Welcome to TIC TAC TOE')

game_on = True

game_board = ['','','','','','','','','','']

turn = turn()

player_assignment()


while game_on == True:




        #WE START BY DISPLAYING THE BOARD

        #NOW WE ASSIGN THE PLAYER 



        #NOW PLAYER1 AND PLAYER2 WILL HAVE GLOBAL ASSIGNMENTS
        #NOW WE WILL DO A FLIP AND SEE WHO STARTS THE GAME


    if turn == 'Player 1':

        print('\n'*100)
        print('Its Player 1 Turn')


        display_board(game_board)
        position = player_choice() 
        place_marker(game_board,player1,position)


        if win_check(game_board,player1) == True:
        
            display_board(game_board)
            print('\n'*100)
            print('Player 1 Has Won!')
            game_on == False

        else:

            if full_board_check(game_board) == True:
            
                display_board(game_board)
                print('\n'*100)
                print('Its a TIE!')

            else:
                turn = 'Player 2'

    else:

        print('\n'*100)
        print('Its Player 2 Turn')

        display_board(game_board)
        position = player_choice() 
        place_marker(game_board,player2,position)

        if win_check(game_board,player2) == True:
        
            display_board(game_board)
            print('\n'*100)
            print('Player 2 Has Won!')
            game_on == False

        else:

            if full_board_check(game_board) == True:
            
                display_board(game_board)
                print('\n'*100)
                print('Its a TIE!')

            else:
            turn = 'Player 1'
```

Comment: Please try to format your question correctly. Right now the code doesnt work like it is in your post.

Comment: Since your board definition is of len = 10, your full_board_check function will never return True.  Have you attempted to test each function separately to verify they each work against known values?